# CheckStyle scan shortcut for IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 15.0.4 with the CheckStyle plugin.

To go to the CheckStyle section, I use <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> and select CheckStyle. The problem is to run the scan, I can do it with the mouse clicking on the Green arrow (see screenshot) but I don't know how to do it with the keyboard.

Someone knows how to do it?

[image: IntellijIdea Checkstyle]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found it,

Ctrl + Alt + S (Settings), Keymap. In the end, Plugins -> Checkstyle-IDEA and assign a shortcut for Check Current File.

Very nice!